# google maps markers is not removing even if the array for marker is null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map with 1 destination and 2 origins (the green marker is the origin and the red is the destination). there is a button that when I click, the markers should be not in the google maps anymore, but when I click the button, the destination and 1 origin are removed, but they're still 1 origin marker even if the original array is already null.

I followed the documentation, but the origin marker is still not removing.

[image: Map with multiple markers] 
here is an example of array of latlong:

```
address_latlong: Array(3)[
  0: {lat: " 51.43037899999999", lon: "6.7507253"}
  1: {lat: " 52.4870183", lon: "13.4249841"}
  2: {lat: " 48.1877566", lon: "11.5949554"}]
```

since the destination and 2 origins are in one array, i used this for getting the last value for destination and the first 2 for the origins. **this is inside a function with the codes for code 1 and code 2**:

```
var originArray = [], destinationValues = {}, originValues = {};
var lastLength = origDest.address_latlong.length;
    destinationValues = {
        destLat: origDest.address_latlong[lastLength-1].lat,
        destLon: origDest.address_latlong[lastLength-1].lon,
    };

    for(var i = lastLength - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        originValues = {
            orgLat: origDest.address_latlong[i].lat,
            orgLon: origDest.address_latlong[i].lon,
        };

        originArray.push(originValues);
    }
```

**[code 1] here is the code for adding the marker for single destination:**

```
if(!findMapNo(1).destination){
    var dest = {
        lat: parseFloat(destinationValues.destLat), 
        lng: parseFloat(destinationValues.destLon)
    };

    //for displaying directions
    route_Search.destination = dest;
    route_Search.destinationName = destinationValues.destName;

    if (findMapNo(1).destination != null) {
       console.log("insert here!!!");
       //findMapNo(1).destination.setMap(null);
       findMapNo(1).destination = [];
       if (findMapNo(1).destination.dragend) {
           google.maps.event.removeListener(findMapNo(1).destination.dragend, 'dragend');
       }
             findMapNo(1).destination = false;
     }

        var icon = {
            url: "http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 54),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        findMapNo(1).destination = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: findMapNo(1).map,
            icon: icon,
            position: dest,
            draggable: false
        });

        findMapNo(1).destination.latLng = dest;
}
```

**[code 2] here is the code for multiple origins:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < originArray.length; i++) {

        if(!findMapNo(1).origin[i]){
            var length = originArray.length;
            console.log("length: ", length);

            var org = {
                lat: parseFloat(originArray[i].orgLat), 
                lng: parseFloat(originArray[i].orgLon)
            };

            route_Search.origin[i] = org;

            if(findMapNo(1).origin[i] != null) {
                console.log("insert");
                console.log(findMapNo(1).origin[i]);
                findMapNo(1).origin[i].setMap(null);
                if (findMapNo(1).origin[i].dragend) { 
             google.maps.event.removeListener(findMapNo(1).origin[i].dragend, 'dragend');
                }
                findMapNo(1).origin[i] = false;
            }   

            // Create a marker for each place.
            findMapNo(1).origin[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: findMapNo(1).map,
                icon: "http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png",
                position: org,
                draggable: false
            });

            findMapNo(1).origin[i].latLng = org;
```

**here is the code of my button for removing markers:**

```
$("#portletHead").on("click", ".backCollectionOrigin", function() {
   if (findMapNo(1).destination) {
        //i used 1 here because the the first data is always empty
        for(var i = 1; i < findMapNo(1).origin.length; i++){
            findMapNo(1).origin[i].setMap(null);
        }

        findMapNo(1).origin = [];
        findMapNo(1).destination.setMap(null);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);

    }

   }
 }
```

function for findMapNo where **arrayMAp = []**:

```
function findMapNo(no) {
    for (i = 0; i < arrayMAp.length; i++) {
        if (arrayMAp[i].mapNo == no) {
            return arrayMAp[i];
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: is there any errors in the console perhaps? because from what I can see, `findMapNo(1).origin[i]` could have a value `false` - which doesn't have a `setMap` method - and that would throw an error so your code would stop running

Comment: there is no error and the findMapNo(1).origin[i] is not null also

Comment: At what point is that **removing markers** code called? is it a function? it's not clear how all those bits of code fit together

Comment: im sorry. its when the button is clicked. ill edit the codes

Comment: The code snippets you posted are not complete, I get a javascript error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: findMapNo is not defined`.  What is `findMapNo(1)`, where is it defined?. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: ill edit the code again. the findMapNo is a function for the arrays of map and markers.

Comment: Is it needed to reproduce the problem?  How is `arrayMAp` initialized (BTW, is that a typo)?

Comment: @geocodezip what do you mean?

Comment: Given the posted code `findMapNo(1)` will cause an error, which won't help me reproduce your issue.  (A working StackOverflow code snippet that demonstrates the issue would be helpful)

Comment: @geocodezip why tho? the marker saved in findMapNo(1) and its working.

Comment: For you maybe. But with the currently posted code, can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: okay. i get your point. but i looked findMapNo as an array... ill try to make a jsfiddle later.

Comment: No need for a JSFiddle. Edit your question and create a code snippet **in the question itself** to provide a [mcve]. Read *minimal* **and** *complete*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your created map markers in an array like this:

```
var markers[];

function addMarkers(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
   });
        markers.push(marker);
}
```

Then, inside the function that removes the marker, you can clear the `markers[]` array and clear your map with markers by doing something like this:

```
function deleteMarkers(){
    for(i=0; i<markers.length;i++){
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
  }
```

Here's a sample implementation that shows how to add and delete markers from map: https://jsbin.com/fuxupecepi/edit?html,output

Note: Please add your own API key on the given sample implementation.